# In the USA today are there congregations who still follow in the footsteps of J C Philpot?

Tags: baptist, united-states

I hope, God willing, to visit the USA sometime and am looking for congregations who follow J C Philpot and J K Popham 'even as they followed Christ' (I Corinthians 11:1). These men denominated themselves 'Gospel Standard Strict Baptists' in the UK during the 19th and 20th centuries.

Are there gatherings in the USA which would be similar?

---

I am aware of the Wikipedia entry which notes only three affiliated congregations (Montana, Michigan, Wisconsin) but I was also interested in any wider following (as there is in the UK) which is not, necessarily, affiliated as such.

---

Note : I am specifically mentioning JCP and JKP because the present day 'articles' of that which is denominated have changed considerably since their time.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Strict_Baptist_churches or https://www.gospelstandard.org.uk/About-Us-2 under the section Our Chapels Today

Comment: The U.S.A. is a very large country - even Colorado is twice the size of the U.K!  Without giving too much away, could you narrow down the geographical area?

Comment: What distinctive are you interested in. I presume closed communion and believer's baptism, but anything else specifically? Sabbath keeping?

Comment: @DJClayworth The first two,  yes. As to the third - personally, I esteem every day (as Paul describes it). But my quest is to find the serious, the reverent, and the followers of good men.

Comment: @NigelJ " the serious, the reverent, and the followers of good men" does not as such narrow it down much. Many denominations consist of people like that, depending on your point of view. However 'closed communion' is going to narrow your search down pretty well.

Comment: I think the general USA geographical scope is fine, the theological position is narrow enough to compensate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest equivalent to the British Strict Baptists in the US is [Primitive Baptists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_Baptists), also called 'Old School Baptists' or 'Hardshell Baptists'. Like the Strict Baptists they practice believer's baptism and closed communion, take the Bible as their only doctrine, and eschew seminary training (they also oppose non-local missions). This [theological statement by an Atlanta Primitive Baptists congregation](http://atlantaprimitivebaptistchurch.org/Questions.htm) gives more detail.

Related groups include the Missionary Baptists. I've been unable to discover if they have closed communion.

The List of Primitive Baptist churches linked from the Wikipedia page gives a list of around sixty congregations throughout the US. Since the Primitive Baptist movement consists of independent congregations with no control or accountability you may find the congregations very different. You should probably be warned that one of the congregations listed has a bad reputation nationwide for extremist inflammatory hate speech.